# load colors from the database and list with color in the background

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

```
enter @foreach ($colors as $color)
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">{{ $color->code }}</th>
                                        <td>{{ $color->name }}</td>
                                        <td> 
                                        <div class="col-md-6 cor"></div>
                                        <style>
                                        .cor {
                                            background-color: {{ $color->code }};
                                              }
                                        </style>
                                        </td>
                                        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Active</span></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="{{ URL::route('edit.customer', array('customer'=>$color->id_color)) }}" class="text-success mr-2">
                                            <button class="nav-icon i-Pen-2 font-weight-bold btn btn-warning m-0" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Editar Cliente"></button>
                                            </a>
                                            <a href="{{ URL::route('delete.customer', array('customer'=>$color->id_color)) }}" class="text-danger mr-2">
                                            <button class="nav-icon i-Close-Window  font-weight-bold btn btn-danger m-0" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Eliminar Cliente"></button>
                                                
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach here
```

I want to load color codes from the database, I want the color that is recorded to appear to the user, this foreach loads me the last color in all

Comment: You should never add style element in middle of your html as you did. Follow ADyson comment

Answer (score 0):

You're generating the CSS rule

```
.cor {
  background-color: {{ $color->code }};
}
```

multiple times, but with a different colour each time. So whatever the last definition is, it just overrides all the previous versions. Think about it - if you declare something with the same name multiple times, how do you expect the browser to tell them apart or know which one to apply to which element? It can't do that. It can only use one version, so it just uses the last one you created.

Since the colour will be unique to each copy of the div, you'd be better off just writing

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: {{ $color->code }}"></div>
```

instead.